# 250+ Keyframes? How to add keyframes?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

How can I increase the amount of keyframes on the dope sheet? I'm animating the rigify add-on and it won't let the green line go past 250(it just restarts). Also the keyframes after 250 are light grey as opposed to the ones before 250 that are darker.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press the <kbd>LMB</kbd> while hovering the cursor over the ***End*** window of a *Timeline* bar and define the number of frames. 
[image]

You may also change the *start* and *end* frames hovering the cursor over *Timeline* and pressing <kbd>S</kbd> for start and <kbd>E</kbd> for the end frame of the animation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the total number of frames in the *Dimensions* panel of the ***Render*** header.
[image]

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer, like screenshots, more explanation, etc.  We discourage one-liners here in favor of more exhaustive, in-depth answers.